# The matrix notation of signum?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory, mathematical-physics

The following question on a notation might look trivial but I am really not sure how to deal with it.

If I have a variable $x$, I could write out:

$$x=|x|\;\text {sgn} (x)$$

a notation that helps me with an operator for the signs that could point to $-1$, $0$ or $+1$.

But then I have a matrix $\bf X$ with elements $x_{i,j}$ while the equation above holds for each element $x_{i,j}$, simply

$$x_{i,j}=|x_{i,j}|\;\text {sgn} (x_{i,j})$$

How does the matrix notation for the equation above look like, in terms of a matrix of $\bf X$ (and not individual elements)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In multidimensioned normed space (e.g. matrices, vectors...) you can define a generalisation of the "sign" by saying
$$sg(x):=\frac{x}{\|x\|},\quad x\ne 0.$$
Then you will obtain that in a any matrix norm
$$X=\|X\|\cdot sg(X).$$

Note, however, there's no widely accepted notation for applying a function to the matrix element-wise, so you're free to introduce your own.

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi, $\|X\|$ is a matrix norm and $sg(X)$ is a matrix.

Comment: which type of norm is the norm you are referring to, is this the spectral norm?

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi, whichever suits you best. As long it's a norm, the aforementioned definition of $sg$ holds and so does the equation for $X$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy ∥.∥ is this norm-1 or norm-2?
if sg(x) = [sg(x1),..,sg(xn)] then sg(x) can be expressed as sg(x) = [x1/|x1|,..,x1/|x1|]. How your answer can explain for this?

Comment: @greenworld as I said before, in my definition the choice of the norm is up to you. However, your definition of $sg(x)$ can not be expressed in these terms. My (one of many possible) definition of signum has intuition "sort of projection on unit sphere", your definition is "take signum pointwise; project on vertices of a unit cube".

Answer (score 4):

The matrix sign function is defined in several equivalent ways. The one closest to what you're asking is

$$\mathop{\rm sign}(A) = A(A^2)^{-1/2}.$$

You can also use Jordan decomposition, integral definition,...

To find more about this, I advise reading Higham's "[Functions of Matrices: Theory and Computation](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/fm/)" (mostly Chapter 5, but some of the other chapters also draw a connection to the sign function).

Answer (score 1):

It is more complicated than it looks. If you have a square complex matrix $A$ you can decompose it into a product 
$$A=UP$$
where $U$ is unitary and $P$ is semidefinite positive. It is a generalization of the decomposition of a complex number $z$ as 
$$z=e^{i\theta} \lvert z \rvert.$$
See [Polar decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) on Wikipedia.

P.S.: Of course this has nothing to do with the sign decomposition of individual entries of the matrix. For that one I am afraid that a unified notation does not exist, so you will have to craft one by yourself.

Comment: This is very interesting but as you say must read far deeper. What is amazing in your way of description is that if $\theta=2 \pi k/n$ one could use roots of unity and build possbly a matrix of corresponding signs to $\bf Z$. Isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

Define the element-wise `abs()` function of the matrix $X$ as follows
$$\eqalign{
A &= {\rm abs}(X) \;\doteq\; {\rm sqrt}\big(X\odot X^*\big) \\
}$$
Also define an element-wise *pseudoinverse* $A^\oplus$ operation
$$
A_{ij}^\oplus = \begin{cases}
\;0\quad&{\rm if}\;A_{ij} = 0 \\
A_{ij}^{-1}\quad&{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
$$
and use this to define an element-wise `sign()` function
$$\eqalign{
S &= {\rm sign}(X) \;\doteq\; X \odot A^\oplus \\
}$$
where $\odot$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product and $X^*$ the complex conjugate.

With this definition, one has the following useful relationships
$$\eqalign{
A\odot S &= X \\
A\odot A &= X\odot X^* \\
}$$

---

All of which describes the element-wise invocation of the Julia sign function

```
S = sign.(X)
```